# How to show a ProgressDialog when MapView (MapBox) is loading on Android?

Tags: android, mapbox

I have an Activity that i use to show a `MapView` from the Android mapbox-sdk.

I am trying show a `ProgressDialog` while the `MapView` is loading , so that i need to *listen* to any load finishing event.

Looking at the Documentation Site, the only available listeners are listed below

- MapView.OnFlingListener
- MapView.OnFpsChangedListener
- MapView.OnInfoWindowClickListener
- MapView.OnMapChangedListener
- MapView.OnMapClickListener
- MapView.OnMapLongClickListener
- MapView.OnMarkerClickListener
- MapView.OnMyLocationChangeListener
- MapView.OnScrollListener

Anyone have done that with the version 2.2.0 of MapBox for Android? It could be a workaround too.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that issue on Mapbox-GL GitHub solves what you are looking for:

https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/630

Comment: Thank you. The listener MapView.OnMapChangedListener() did the trick. For Android the method names is very similar to the JS implementation.